# Can't access csrf cookie sent by server via Set-Cookie (Django + Angular2)

Tags: django, cookies, setcookie, django-csrf

I'm experimenting with an app running on Angular 2 in the frontend and Django as API and I can't access the CSRF cookie sent from Django.

As you can see, I am getting back the cookie from the server but I cannot access it from the browser (`document.cookie`) or Angular 2 (using the `ng2-cookies` module).

[image: Set-Cookie response header]

Everything was working while testing on `localhost`, now client and server are running on different hosts and this might be the reason of the problem.

- Client running on https://django-angular2-movies.firebaseapp.com/
- Server running on https://glacial-shore-18891.herokuapp.com

This is part of the settings I'm using on Django:

**settings.py**

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['django-angular2-movies.firebaseapp.com']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Other things that I have tried, but didn't help:

- Removing the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting
- Adding `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'django-angular2-movies.firebaseapp.com'`
- Using `{ withCredentials: true }` in the request sent from the client
- Using the `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator on Django views

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: At any point was the cookie marked as "httponly"? Don't think browsers will downgrade it, once set. Worth verifying by either clearing cookies or inspecting the cookie store for the attribute.

Comment: Nope it was never set as `httponly`, also I was clearing the cookies each time I was conducting a new test.

Comment: In the end I was not able to solve the problem, the cookie was being set by the `Set-Cookie` header but I couldn't get it via javascript unless both client and server where on `localhost`. So I simply decided to send the csrf cookie via json and store it in `localStorage`.

Comment: Now that I think about it more...the cookie header is not part of the page requested by the browser? But via a seperate request? So are you looking in the right 'document'?

Comment: Man... I don't know honestly. As far as I know I should be able to access that cookie. What do you mean by "are you looking at the right `document`" ?

Comment: Since you fetch the cookie via Ajax, it is not the same request the browser makes, so it may not be available in `window.document.cookies`, especially if "allow third-party cookies" is off. Sending it via json is the right solution though and much more reliable.